# D3 Bubble chart in Reactjs has empty circles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, bubble-chart

I am using d3 v7 in a ReactJS 17.0.2 project. I'd like to integrate the code shown here:
https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/bubble_tooltip.html
I receive the data from the function props, but if I pass them directly to svg.append().data() I get the axis shown ok, but the bubbles do not show.
The code I use to create the circles is this:

```
function D3BubbleChart({ input }) {

  const ref = useD3(
    (svg) => {
/* some margin, tooltip and axis stuff here */
...
/* then I try to create the circles like this */

svg
   .append("g")
   .selectAll("dot")
   .data(mydata)
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class", "bubbles")
   .attr("cx", (d) => x(d.average_value))
   .attr("cy", (d) => y(d.average_price))
   .attr("r", (d) => z(d.pieces))
   .style("fill", "red")
   .on("mouseover", showTooltip)
   .on("mousemove", moveTooltip)
   .on("mouseleave", hideTooltip)
```

Everything else (axis, tooltips...) seem to be built OK, but the nodes are empty. The Svg element in the HTML page looks like this:

```
<svg style="height: 500px; width: 100%; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
  <g id="plot-area">
    <svg width="500" height="420">
      <g transform="translate(50,10)">
      <g transform="translate(0, 380)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle">...</g>
      <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(36.33333333333333,0)">...</g>
...
      </svg><div class="tooltip" style="opacity: 0; background-color: black; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; color: white;"></div></g>
    <g class="x-axis"></g>
  <g class="y-axis"></g>
</svg>
```

I copied only the relevant elements to show that the g elements are empty. Am I maybe using d3 v6 code for d3 v7? I was not able to find documentation specific to bubble charts for d3 v7.
I checked data and it contains data, but I also tried to hardcode scalar values for cx, cy and r with the same result. I feel that the problem might be related to the creation of the circles.

Comment: What do you mean they are empty? The circles render, but they are not filled with any color?

Comment: They do not appear at all, the <g> elements in the HTML contain nothing as shown here. I managed to have it working by putting the code above within a d3.json() callback. But in reality I don't need to re-read the data from the file as I already receive them in the function props. But if I try to pass the data directly to the svg.append() call, I get nothing in the HTML. I will edit the question with this additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get it working. I post here the code for others trying to do the same thing.

```
const ref = useD3(
    (svg) => {
      // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
      const margin = { top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 1080 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


      // append the svg object to the body of the page
      svg = d3
        .select("#plot-area")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

      // Add X axis
      const x = d3.scaleLog().domain([1, 2000]).range([0, width]);
      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // Add Y axis
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 4]).range([height, 0]).nice();
      svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      // Add a scale for bubble size
      const z = d3.scaleLog().domain([1, 1000]).range([1, 100]);

      

      // -1- Create a tooltip div that is hidden by default:
      const tooltip = d3
        .select("#plot-area")
        .append("div")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("background-color", "black")
        .style("border-radius", "5px")
        .style("padding", "10px")
        .style("color", "white");

      // -2- Create 3 functions to show / update (when mouse move but stay on same circle) / hide the tooltip
      const showTooltip = function (event, d) {
        tooltip.transition().duration(200);
        tooltip
          .style("opacity", 1)
          .html("Collection: " + d.name + " " + d.tokens + " tokens")
          .style("left", event.x / 2 + "px")
          .style("top", event.y / 2 + 30 + "px");
      };
      const moveTooltip = function (event, d) {
        tooltip
          .style("left", event.x / 2 + "px")
          .style("top", event.y / 2 + 30 + "px");
      };
      const hideTooltip = function (event, d) {
        tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0);
      };

      // Add dots
      svg
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(input)
        .join("circle")
        .attr("class", "bubbles")
        .attr("cx", (d) => x(d.average_value))
        .attr("cy", (d) => y(d.average_price))
        .attr("r", (d) => z(d.pieces))
        .style("fill", "red")
        // -3- Trigger the functions
        .on("mouseover", function () {
          return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
        })
        .on("mousemove", function (event) {
          return tooltip
            .style("top", event.pageY + "px")
            .style("left", event.pageX + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
          return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
        });
```